# Azure SQL Geo Replication - Traffic Manager

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-traffic-manager

We have 3 replicas in geo replicated database setup in Azure. Is there a way to configure a one or more listener which we can change to point to any of the geo replicated database endpoint to avoid changing connection strings at client side. The failover group has a capability of listener but I can only include 2 sql db in it so looking for an alternative. I have also checked if I can use traffic manager to point to sql endpoints and doesn't seems a way to do this.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information on the SQL side of things? Are you hosting on a VM, a SQL Managed Instance, Azure SQL?

You mention you can only include 2 SQL DB (I'm assuming you mean server here) in your failover group, am I right then in thinking you're running a standard edition of SQL?

How are you replicating the data to the 3rd replica if you've only got two nodes in your failover group?

How is the client accessing the database currently? Over the public internet, a private endpoint etc?

Comment: @AnthonyNorwood, I am using Azure SQL with Business tier and have 3 replica in Geo replication.  In Failover group we can only add 2 replicas of the DB. I have 3 replicas of the same DB. Clients are access the DB through public endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

### There are two options which you can try.

The **read scale-out feature** allows you to offload read-only workloads using the compute capacity of one of the read-only replicas, instead of running them on the read-write replica. This way, some read-only workloads can be isolated from the read-write workloads, and will not affect their performance.

If your SQL connection string is configured with `ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly`, the application will be redirected to a read-only replica of that database or managed instance.

Check [Use read-only replicas to offload read-only query workloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/read-scale-out) for more details.

**Active geo-replication** is a feature that lets you to create a continuously synchronized readable secondary database for a primary database. The readable secondary database may be in the same Azure region as the primary, or, more commonly, in a different region.

You can refer [Active geo-replication terminology and capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/active-geo-replication-overview#active-geo-replication-terminology-and-capabilities) to know more.

Comment: Hi Utkarsh, My question was specific to creating a listener for 3 replicas of geo replicated database. Is there a way I can use traffic manager to add listener for 3 replicas?